# How to remove namespace from then signature elements in Xades4J signature?

Tags: java, x509certificate, xades4j

I have the following code, that imports content.xml into document.xml and signs the document.xml root element.

```
try {
            KeyingDataProvider kp = new FileSystemKeyStoreKeyingDataProvider(
                    "pkcs12", 
                    "C:\\workspace\\tests\\my\\LG.pfx",
                    new FirstCertificateSelector(),
                    new DirectPasswordProvider("mykeypass"),
                    new DirectPasswordProvider("mykeypass"), 
                    true);
            XadesSigningProfile p = new XadesBesSigningProfile(kp);
            XadesSigner signer = p.newSigner();

            javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory factory = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder builder = null;
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();


            Document doc1 = builder.parse(new File("C:\\workspace\\tests\\document.xml"));
            Document doc2 = builder.parse(new File("C:\\workspace\\tests\\content.xml"));

            Node contentElement = doc2.getDocumentElement();
            Node parentElement = doc1.getDocumentElement();
            Node adoptedContentElement = doc1.adoptNode(contentElement);
            parentElement.appendChild(adoptedContentElement);

            Node nodeToSign = doc1.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild();
            Node nodeToAttachSignature = doc1.getDocumentElement();

            IndividualDataObjsTimeStampProperty dataObjsTimeStamp = new IndividualDataObjsTimeStampProperty();
            AllDataObjsCommitmentTypeProperty globalCommitment = AllDataObjsCommitmentTypeProperty.proofOfApproval();
            CommitmentTypeProperty commitment = CommitmentTypeProperty.proofOfCreation();   

            DataObjectDesc obj = new EnvelopedXmlObject(nodeToSign, "text/xml", null);
            SignedDataObjects dataObjs = new SignedDataObjects(obj).withCommitmentType(globalCommitment); 

            signer.sign(dataObjs, nodeToAttachSignature);

            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            Result output = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\workspace\\tests\\signedDocument.xml"));
            Source input = new DOMSource(doc1);
            transformer.transform(input, output);


        } catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XadesProfileResolutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XAdES4jException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

that produces the signature like:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-26102a68-cfea-43fd-a40e-9682ae7da4a1">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
```

The question is - how to remove namespace `ds:` from the signature elements?

Answer (score 2):

I saw a line where the prefix "ds" is set in an example named [CreateSignature](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/santuario/xml-security-java/tags/1.5.3/samples/org/apache/xml/security/samples/signature/CreateSignature.java), for the Apache Santuario library in Java.

```
ElementProxy.setDefaultPrefix(Constants.SignatureSpecNS, "ds");
```

In the book written by the developer of the library, he specifies how to define the signature, because XAdES4j is mostly to build the signature and not the whole document:

> 5.2 Signature Production: as previously discussed, a signature can be seen as having two parts: the first consists of the characteristics of
>   the signer and the signature operation itself; the second, the
>   resources being signed. If the signer is seen as a regular signature
>   producer, he’s likely to have a set of characteristics that are used
>   whenever a signature is created, i.e a signature profile. These
>   characteristics are fixed between signatures, while the signed
>   resources vary. Thus, producing a signature is to combine a profile
>   and a set of resources in order to create the final XML structure.
>   This process comes down to three major tasks: gather the needed
>   information (signature and data objects properties, algorithms, keying
>   data) in appropriate order; **create the core signature structure using
>   the Apache XML Security API**; and create the qualifying properties DOM
>   tree to be appended to the signature. **Note that Apache XML Security
>   creates the DOM tree for the core signature structure. However, the
>   XAdES elements are unknown to the Apache API**, which means that the
>   last task has to be completely supported by the library.

cited from: XAdES4j — a Java Library for XAdES Signature Services. By Luís Filipe dos Santos Gonçalves

Answer (score 1):

By "removing namespace" I think you meaning removing the prefix. This is not somethign you can control via xades4j because the default prefixes are [set by Apache Santuario](https://github.com/apache/santuario-java/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/xml/security/utils/ElementProxy.java#L507) and then used when [creating a XMLSignature](https://github.com/apache/santuario-java/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/xml/security/signature/XMLSignature.java#L331). The defaults seem to be [set on the Init class](https://github.com/apache/santuario-java/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/xml/security/Init.java); I'm not sure how/if to override the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put into your code:

```
Constants.setSignatureSpecNSprefix("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use java version 6.32 or above to avoid appending ds: in signed XML